# Modifying the value of an array in a function by a pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have read quite a few articles about how to do it, but I can't seem to get my head about what is the problem in my code. I have done multiple test, but none seems to work.

My problem is pretty easy, I have declared an array, pass it to a function, modify it in the function, and return the modified value to the main.

I think I know how to do it, by passing the value by reference. I have tested with integer variables and it works, but I can't seem to get to work with arrays of characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void func1(char *puntf);

int main ()
{
    char DIRECTORIO[200];
    char *punt = 0;

    getcwd(DIRECTORIO, 200);
    punt=&DIRECTORIO;

    printf("DIR in MAIN is: \t%s\n\n", DIRECTORIO);
    printf("PUNT in MAIN is: \t%s\n\n", punt);

    func1(punt);

    printf("DIR in MAIN after func1 is: \t%s\n\n", punt);

    return 0;
}

void func1(char *puntf)
{
    char DIRF[200]="/Users";
    char *puntero = 0;

    printf("puntf from MAIN in func1 es: \t%s\n\n", puntf);
    printf("DIRF in func1 is: \t%s\n\n",DIRF);
    puntf=DIRF;

    printf ("puntero in func1 is:\t%s\n\n", puntero);
    printf ("puntf in func1 is:\t%s\n\n", puntf);

}
```

If I use *puntf=DIRF; it changes the first letter of the directory from 'C' to 'P'.

If I use *puntf=*DIRF; it changes the first letter of the directory from 'C' to '\'.

In several other options, the executable crashes.

I have tried lots of possibilities while assigning DIRF value to puntf (really lots), but I can't figure out how to get it.

Please, could anyone point me to my mistake?

Thanks,
Juan

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues. First of all `punt = &DIRECTORIO;` doesn't compile.

`puntf=DIRF;` will only change the local `puntf`, but not the `punt` pointer in main.

And anyway with `puntf=DIRF;` you are trying to assign a pointer to the local variable `DIRF`. Be aware that `puntf=DIRF;` doesnt copy a string, it only assigns a pointer. If you want to copy a string, you need the [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) function.

You probbaly want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void func1(char *puntf);

int main()
{
  char DIRECTORIO[200];
  char *punt = 0;

  getcwd(DIRECTORIO, 200);

  printf("DIR in MAIN after func1 is: \t%s\n\n", DIRECTORIO);
  func1(DIRECTORIO);
  printf("DIR in MAIN after func1 is: \t%s\n\n", DIRECTORIO);

  return 0;
}

void func1(char *puntf)
{
  char DIRF[200] = "/Users";
  printf("puntf from MAIN in func1 es: \t%s\n\n", puntf);
  printf("DIRF in func1 is: \t%s\n\n", DIRF);

  strcpy(puntf, DIRF);

  printf("puntf in func1 is:\t%s\n\n", puntf);
}
```

Comment: @ Michael, thank you very much. I have come back to Uni after more than 15 years, and it's been a long time since the last time that I programed anything. You won't believe it, but I've been with this problem more than 25-30 hours. I have read a lot, watch videos on youtube, I bought a book, and I haven't been able to get it right. And it was dead easy, I was just complicating things a lot. **You have make my day. Thanks, thanks, thanks.**